# Query with different conditions in same table with same columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have this table (url_table):

```
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id | language_code |     url     |
+----+---------------+-------------+
| 60 | de            | german_url  |
| 60 | en            | english_url |
| 60 | fr            | france_url  |
| 60 | es            | spanish_url |
+----+---------------+-------------+
```

I want to combine this two queries in one:

```
SELECT url FROM url_table WHERE id = 60 AND language_code = 'de';
SELECT url FROM url_table WHERE id = 60 AND language_code = 'en';
```

the result should be the german and english url, but renamed as url_de and url_en:

```
url_de: german_url
url_en: english_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `in`

```
SELECT url 
FROM url_table 
WHERE id = 60 AND language_code in ('de','en');
```

From you expect result you can try to use `concat` function.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT concat('url_',language_code ,':',url)
FROM url_table
WHERE id = 60 AND language_code in ('de','en');

| concat('url_',language_code ,':',url) |
| ------------------------------------- |
| url_de:german_url                     |
| url_en:english_url                    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR`

```
SELECT url FROM url_table WHERE id = 60 AND language_code = 'de' OR language_code = 'en' ;
```

Comment: be careful, this don't match the requirements. You have the same `url` column in both rows: *"but renamed as url_de and url_enbut renamed as url_de and url_en"*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure syntax is perfect, but maybe something like this.

```
SELECT 
  u.id 
, url_de = (SELECT URL FROM url_table u2 WHERE u2.ID = u.id AND u2.language_code ='de')
, url_en = (SELECT URL FROM url_table u2 WHERE u2.ID = u.id AND u2.language_code ='de')
FROM url_table u
WHERE u.id = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation or a join:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN language_code = 'de' THEN url END) as url_de,
       MAX(CASE WHEN language_code = 'en' THEN url END) as url_en      
FROM url_table
WHERE id = 60 AND language_code IN ('de', 'en')
```

This will work for an arbitrary number of `id`s if you use `group by`:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN language_code = 'de' THEN url END) as url_de,
       MAX(CASE WHEN language_code = 'en' THEN url END) as url_en      
FROM url_table
WHERE language_code IN ('de', 'en')
GROUP BY id;
```

You can also use a self-join:

```
select de.url as url_de, en.url as url_en
from url_table de join
     url_table en
     on de.id = en.id and
        de.language_code = 'de' and
        en.language_code = 'en'
where de.id = 60;
```

However, this gets tricky if you don't have rows for both languages, which is why I recommend the `group by` approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT concat('url_',language_code ,':  ',url) As url
 FROM url_table
 WHERE id = 60 AND (language_code = 'de' OR language_code = 'en');
```

out put:

[image]